# Starling splash screen lag issue

Tags: actionscript, lag, splash-screen

i am making a game based on starling in flash professional , i have like 5 spritesheets to load thats why i decided to put a animation as splash screen.

i create the splash by creating an object of the splash screen. The problem i am facing is that the game when loaded stucks on the frame 1 of the splash animation , then when the entire game is loaded then only the animation starts , thus defeating the purpose of having splash screen in the first place,

how can i do it so that the splash animation begins instantly and spritesheets are loaded concurrently.

here is the code i used in the document class to add splash screen

the splash class contains animation made in flash professional

```
splash = new Splash();
splash.width = 1136;
splash.height = 800;
splash.y = 67;


splash.width = stage.fullScreenWidth;
splash.height = (stage.fullScreenHeight / 640) *550;
this.addChild(splash);
splash.play();
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure about the total setup of your flash file but this is how I do it.

On Scene1 I have the splash movie clip. The actually game is on Scene2.
In the splash movie clip, last frame, check whether the game movie clip has loaded, if not, go back to frame one of the splash movie clip. If it is fully loaded, `stop();` the splash movie clip and `goToAndPlay("Scene2");`

Comment: can you tell me how to do that via coding ? , i am not putting splash directly on stage.

Comment: Not sure. Can you add the code you already have in a separate movie clip and add the necessary action to that? I have worked with Flash a lot, years back. Don't have the latest version of it, so I can't test it for you.